# MATLAB legend() Function in for-loop- add entry in every loop

Tags: matlab

i have searched a lot but i did not manage to create a for-loop, or something similar in order to add an extra entry in the legend area in every loop.
For example: 1st loop- 1 entry in the legend
             2nd loop- 2 entries in the legend...
i have tried the legappend function but i get errors, even with examples that are provided.
Below you can see a section of my code:

```
    Eb_N0_dB = [-10:25];        
    k_dB=[-inf 10 20];             
    figure(1)
    hold on
    semilogy(Eb_N0_dB,simBer);
    legend(sprintf('sim (nTx=2, nRx=2 k=%d, Alamouti)',k_dB(1)))
    legend boxoff

    for qq=2:length(k_dB)
    legappend(sprintf('sim (nTx=2, nRx=2 k=%d, Alamouti)',k_dB(qq)))
    end

   %%simBer is a {length(k_dB),length(Eb_N0_dB)} matrix
```

i  get the error below

```
    Error using legend (line 120)
    Invalid argument. Type 'help legend' for more information.

    Error in legappend (line 74)
    [legend_h,object_h,plot_h,text_strings] = legend(h,allDatah,str);
```

Any suggestions?
Regards

Comment: This problem only affects matlab 2014b or later.

Comment: It may be worth noting that `legappend` is not part of the standard MATLAB library and you have to get it through FEX: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47228-legappend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I create an empty variable and then add *cell array elements of strings* for each legend entry.  Appending a legend entry at the point in code where you add a plot is a convenient way to keep things organized - otherwise you may have blank or doubled legend entires:

```
x = 1:4;
figure
hold all

L ='';
%L = cell(1,N);

for j = 1:length(x)

    scatter(j,x(j),60,'filled');
    L = [L,{num2str(j)}];

end

%additional plots are easily added or taken out, leaving the legend in tact:
scatter(rand,rand,90,'x','linewidth',3);
L = [L,'optional data a'];

scatter(rand,rand,90,'x','linewidth',3);
L = [L,'optional data b'];

legend(L);
```

Comment: Thnx for your fast reply. May i ask you  how i can also add text in the legend

Comment: just replace num2str(j) (in the for loop) with whatever string you want.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @MMichail note the grouping of the strings, as: ['str1','str2'].  Also, I preallocated cell array L... the only time you wouldn't want to do this is if you aren't sure how many entries you will have when allocating, in which case the appending method works better:  L = [L,{'new_entry'}].

Comment: `sprintf` is dramatically faster than `strcat`, which is why I used it when I edited the answer. Not sure why someone changed it back.

Comment: You can test my proposition: 
`>> n = 1e+4; tic; for ii = 1:n; strcat('hi','mom'); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.658291 seconds.
>> n = 1e+4; tic; for ii = 1:n; sprintf('%s%s','hi','mom'); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.099812 seconds.`

Comment: @anon0909 Thank you very  for your time i appreciate your help

Comment: @MMichail glad I could help.

Comment: Nice job on the cell array. +1.

Comment: @transversalitycondition yes, it's much faster.  Given that the author was already using my original answer, I was somewhat reluctant to change the format on him.

Comment: @transversalitycondition - Edits that change what the person wrote aren't very welcome.  However, edits that fix typos or perhaps clarify the language written are fine.  However, code changes if merited, you should ask for permission first, then make the edit.  anon0909 probably changed it back because that's the code that he/she prefers.  Even though you had the best of intentions, I personally find it a bit rude.

Comment: @rayryeng I apologize. I re-read it and I was unintentionally rude. I also did not understand that substantive edits were unacceptable -- noted.

Comment: @transversalitycondition that's fine. No need to apologize. FWIW, `sprintf` is certainly faster!